# Non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer member. Error on display function c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to get a display function to hold the information from the floats and when I try to run the program it gives me the error "Non-standard syntax; use '&" to create a pointer member" and then I add the '&' to the floats and make them pointers and it gives me the error "'&': illegal operation on bound member function expression. I dont know why it wont work.

heres my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;


class Rectangle
{

public:

//constructor
Rectangle() { }


//accessor
float GetHeight() { return m_height; } const
float GetWidth() { return m_width; } const

float GetArea() { return m_height * m_width; }

float GetPerimeter() { return m_height + m_height + m_width + m_width; }

//mutator
void SetHeight(float h)
{
    cout << "Please Enter height: \n";
    cin >> h;

};

void SetWidth(float w)
{
    cout << "Please Enter the width: \n";
    cin >> w;
}


void Display()
{
    cout << "Height: " << GetHeight << " " << "Width: " << GetWidth << " " << "Area: " << GetArea << " " << "Perimeter: " << GetPerimeter << endl;

};



private:

float m_height;
float m_width;

};



   using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Rectangle r;
    float height = 0;
    float width = 0;
    r.SetHeight(height);
    r.SetWidth(width);

    r.Display();





    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GetHeight is not a variable, but a function, add parenthesis:

```
void Display()
{
    cout << "Height: " << GetHeight() << " " << "Width: " << GetWidth() << " " << "Area: " << GetArea() << " " << "Perimeter: " << GetPerimeter() << endl;

};
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This allowed me to finally open the program and enter in the data

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what gabonator said, you may also want to set the object's value:

```
void SetHeight(float h)
{
    cout << "Please Enter height: \n";
    cin >> h;
    m_height = h;

};
```

Comment: Thank you for this as well because it stored the entered data and allowed me to do the math and display it in the end